# Expecting single values but multivalues

Tags: javascript, html

I am sorting an array of alphanumerics entered in an input field by the user and the result is correct.

```
const sortedNumbers = values.sort(function (a, b){
    if (a > b) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
});

Array(3) [ "2a", "2b", "2f" ]
```

However, when displaying the result in HTML using the script below, I was expecting each alphanumeric in one span

```
document.querySelector('.pyramid').innerHTML = sortedNumbers.map(val => `<span class="values">${values}</span>`).join('');
```

The result however is three spans with all three alphanumerics

```
<span class="values">2a,2b,2f</span><span class="values">2a,2b,2f</span><span class="values">2a,2b,2f</span>
```

Now I am wondering, can I separate the alphanumerics so that they are each in their own span?

Comment: `.map(val => <span class="values">${values}</span>\`)` typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `values` in your template string instead of `val`

```
document.querySelector('.pyramid').innerHTML = sortedNumbers.map(val => `<span class="values">${val}</span>`).join('');
```

Comment: Typo questions are off-topic - commenting is appropriate, answering isn't. (the question has no chance of having value for any future visitor)

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks. Is https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174389/should-we-answer-or-comment-on-a-typo-question most relevant?

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't see that!